# Extending String.prototype performance shows that function calls are 10x faster

Tags: javascript, performance

I wanted to extend String object prototype with some utility method. It worked, but the performance was surprisingly low. Passing a string to a function is 10x times faster than overriding the `String.prototype` method that is doing the same thing. To make sure this really happens I created a very simple `count()` function and the corresponding methods.

(I was experimenting, and created three different versions of the method.)

```
function count(str, char) {
    var n = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) if (str[i] == char) n++;
    return n;
}

String.prototype.count = function (char) {
    var n = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) if (this[i] == char) n++;
    return n;
}

String.prototype.count_reuse = function (char) {
    return count(this, char)
}

String.prototype.count_var = function (char) {
    var str = this;
    var n = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) if (str[i] == char) n++;
    return n;
}

// Here is how I measued speed, using Node.js 6.1.0

var STR ='0110101110010110100111010011101010101111110001010110010101011101101010101010111111000';
var REP = 1e3//6;

console.time('func')
for (var i = 0; i < REP; i++) count(STR,'1')
console.timeEnd('func')

console.time('proto')
for (var i = 0; i < REP; i++) STR.count('1')
console.timeEnd('proto')

console.time('proto-reuse')
for (var i = 0; i < REP; i++) STR.count_reuse('1')
console.timeEnd('proto-reuse')

console.time('proto-var')
for (var i = 0; i < REP; i++) STR.count_var('1')
console.timeEnd('proto-var')
```

Results:

```
func: 705 ms
proto: 10011 ms
proto-reuse: 10366 ms
proto-var: 9703 ms
```

As you can see the difference is dramatic.

The below proves that performance of method calls is neglectably slower, and that the function code **it self** is slower for methods.

```
function count_dummy(str, char) {
    return 1234;
}

String.prototype.count_dummy = function (char) {
    return 1234; // Just to prove that accessing the method is not the bottle-neck.
}

console.time('func-dummy')
for (var i = 0; i < REP; i++) count_dummy(STR,'1')
console.timeEnd('func-dummy')

console.time('proto-dummy')
for (var i = 0; i < REP; i++) STR.count_dummy('1')
console.timeEnd('proto-dummy')

console.time('func-dummy')
for (var i = 0; i < REP; i++) count_dummy(STR,'1')
console.timeEnd('func-dummy')
```

Results:

```
func-dummy: 0.165ms
proto-dummy: 0.247ms
```

Although on huge repetitions (like 1e8) prototyped methods proves to be 10x times slower than functions, this can be ignored for this case.

All this may be related only to a String object, because simple generic objects perform about the same when you pass them to functions or call their methods:

```
var A = { count: 1234 };

function getCount(obj) { return obj.count }

A.getCount = function() { return this.count }

console.time('func')
for (var i = 0; i < 1e9; i++) getCount(A)
console.timeEnd('func')

console.time('method')
for (var i = 0; i < 1e9; i++) A.getCount()
console.timeEnd('method')
```

Results:

```
func: 1689.942ms
method: 1674.639ms
```

I've been searching on Stackoverflow and binging, but other that the recommendation "do not extend String or Array because you pollute the name space" (which is not a problem for my particular project), I cannot find anything related to performance of methods compared to functions. So should I simply forget about extending the String object due to performance drop of added methods or there is more about it?

Comment: Thanks for your information but, you're last implementation is far away from `prototype` you can replace object with function and then add prototype method. then get a new instance of it. BTW result is the same.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is most likely because you are not using strict mode, and the `this` value inside your method is getting coerced to a `String` instance instead of being a primitive string. This coercion, and further method calls or property accesses on the `String` object, are slower than using primitive values.

You can (*Edit*: could, at least, in 2016) confirm this by repeating your measurement on `var STR = new String('01101011…')` which should have less overhead.

Then fix your implementation:

```
String.prototype.count = function (char) {
    "use strict";
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^
    var n = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++)
        if (this[i] == char)
            n++;
    return n;
};
```

Comment: It works, but does not make sense to me! Thus I added a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38411552/why-use-strict-improves-performance-10x-in-this-example

Comment: @exebook: As I said, sloppy mode casts the `this` value to an object, so it needs to create a `String` instance on every call, which is quite some overhead for such a simple method as yours

Comment: @Bergi I don't understand why the following doesn't fix the problem:  `const testString = new String('Hello World!'); for (let i = 0; i < 11111111; i++) testString.hash();` Would you be able to add to your answer? See [live example](https://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/31z27uef/)

Comment: @JuanMendes Maybe it's just that `charCodeAt` in [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70513684/1048572) is slower on string objects than on strings? I swear that in 2016, calling `new String` upfront did make a difference for accessing `this[i]`.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks, just trying to make sure I wasn't missing anything. Maybe update the answer to explain that the only way to fix it is to "use strict"? I tried a million things to prevent this problem by boxing the string myself or by calling the prototype methods directly and it's always slow.