# Why "use strict" improves performance 10x in this example?

Tags: javascript, performance

Following the question [Extending String.prototype performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38407760/extending-string-prototype-performance-shows-that-function-calls-are-10x-faster) I am really intrigued, because just adding `"use strict"` to a `String.prototype` method improved performance 10 times. The [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38410199/1968972) by [bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi) is short and does not explain it to me. Why there is such a dramatic difference between two almost identical methods, that only differ in `"use strict"` at the top? Can you explain in more detail and with the theory behind this?

```js
String.prototype.count = function(char) {
  var n = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++)
    if (this[i] == char) n++;
  return n;
};

String.prototype.count_strict = function(char) {
  "use strict";
  var n = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++)
    if (this[i] == char) n++;
  return n;
};
// Here is how I measued speed, using Node.js 6.1.0

var STR = '0110101110010110100111010011101010101111110001010110010101011101101010101010111111000';
var REP = 1e4;

console.time('proto');
for (var i = 0; i < REP; i++) STR.count('1');
console.timeEnd('proto');

console.time('proto-strict');
for (var i = 0; i < REP; i++) STR.count_strict('1');
console.timeEnd('proto-strict');
```

Result:

```
proto: 101 ms
proto-strict: 7.5 ms
```

Comment: Can you do a test with `this[i] === char` and see if you get the same difference?

Comment: I tested with `this[i] === char` in a DOM environment and the result is the same

Comment: bergi's explanation says that when you call the `count` function, the `this` parameter has to be cast to a string object instead of a string literal whereas in strict mode it does not have to in order to operate correctly.  Why this is the case is beyond me, I'm very interested in the answer.

Comment: @NickLarsen: It's just how the language was spec'd. Traditionally JS would make sure you always had an object as `this`, but in strict mode it skips that step, so you get the *primitive* string, or whatever was provided for `this`.

Comment: It's time to put `"use strict";` everywhere boys! Goooold

Comment: Have you had a look at [What does “use strict” do in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1335851/1048572) and [How does the “this” keyword work?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3127429/1048572)?

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13055/what-is-boxing-and-unboxing-and-what-are-the-trade-offs

Answer (score 163, accepted):

[In strict mode, the `this` context is not forced to be an object.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode#Securing_JavaScript) If you call a function on a non-object, `this` will just be that non-object.

In contrast, in non-strict mode, the `this` context is always first wrapped in an object if it's not already an object. For example, `(42).toString()` first wraps `42` in a `Number` object and then calls `Number.prototype.toString` with the `Number` object as `this` context. In strict mode, the `this` context is left untouched and just calls `Number.prototype.toString` with `42` as `this` context.

```js
(function() {
  console.log(typeof this);
}).call(42); // 'object'

(function() {
  'use strict';
  console.log(typeof this);
}).call(42); // 'number'
```

In your case, the non-strict mode version spends a lot of time wrapping and unwrapping primitive `string`s into `String` object wrappers and back. The strict mode version on the other hand directly works on the primitive `string`, which improves performance.

Comment: And the removal of `with` also helps a bit for every variable lookup iirc.

Comment: @zzzzBov incorrect. Removal of `with` helps _immensely_ as it allows the browser to reason which variable expression refers to which variable.

Comment: Theoretically, `this.length` and `this[i]` should also create a string exotic object (string primitives don't have properties), but probably browsers don't do it.

Comment: I tested with `String` objects and the time was the same for each function (after allowing for experimental error). They were also six times faster than the non-strict version and 17 times slower than the strict version were on raw strings on my system. I also added `var self = String(this);` etc. to the non-strict version and this actually brought the speed up to the same as the strict version for `String` objects but raw strings were still 50% slower, presumably due to the `String` construction overhead.

Comment: Seems unintuitive to me that non-object `this` is "stricter" than always-object `this`.

Comment: @IllidanS4: This is mostly about cases where `this` is `null` or `undefined`, which would be the global object in sloppy mode.

Comment: @IllidanS4: Think of it as "actual `this`" vs. "wrapper `this`" if you like. Object wrappers are a kludge that should never have existed, so it makes sense that strict mode would avoid them more when possible.

Comment: So should we always use `strict mode` if we work with `this`?

Comment: @EdwardBlack Strict mode fixes some mistakes in JavaScript's 'old' semantics, helps you prevent bugs by turning silent errors into actual errors, and enables browsers to better optimize your code. You should *always* use strict mode if you're writing new JavaScript code today. However, enabling strict mode may break legacy code, so be careful when you're transitioning old code to modern JavaScript.