# Why are my prototypes so slow?

Tags: javascript, prototype, benchmarking

Okay so I wrote this simple javascript function to make my code more readable:

```
Number.prototype.isBetween=function(a,b){
    return(this>=a&&this<b);
};
```

Now this turns out to be VERY slow: I tried this "benchmark" (I don't really know how to properly do this stuff but this proves my point either way):

```
var res=0;
var k=20;
var t=new Date().getTime();
for(var i=0;i<10000000;i++){if(k.isBetween(13,31)){res++;}}
console.log(new Date().getTime()-t);
```

versus

```
var res=0;
var k=20;
var t=new Date().getTime();
for(var i=0;i<10000000;i++){if(k>=13&&k<31)){res++;}}
console.log(new Date().getTime()-t);
```

and the first script takes about 3000ms in chrome (and chrome is what I'm using and what I'm interested in), whereas the second script takes only 24ms - a whole factor 125 *faster*. Is extending the existing classes javascript provides just a really bad idea? What is going on here?

Comment: Extending existing classes may not be a bad idea (see jQuery plugins) but extending **standard built-in classes** is a bad idea because future versions of javascript may break your code. Read about what happened to prototype.js

Comment: Constant propagation. The term you're looking for is [*constant propagation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding). In your second script, there's not only no function call, there's likely not even a computation happing at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extending String.prototype performance shows that function calls are 10x faster](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38407760/1048572)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason is that for the method `isBetween` to be applied, the subject *k* needs to be converted to a `Number` object. This is called *boxing* or [*primitive wrapping*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive#Primitive_wrapper_objects_in_JavaScript).

Then the `isBetween` method is applied where the comparison operator `>` will need to retrieve the primitive value from the `this` object, ... twice.

This is all additional overhead that comes on top of the additional function call (involving the stack).

This total overhead is more work than the actual comparison that needs to happen, and so the performance impact is relatively huge.

#### Strict mode

As @Bergi mentioned in the comments below, the above-described wrapping [does not happen in strict mode <sup>MDN</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode#Securing_JavaScript) :

> the value passed as `this` to a function in *strict mode* is not forced into being an object (a.k.a. "boxed"). [...] automatic boxing [is] a performance cost [...] Thus for a strict mode function, the specified `this` is not boxed into an object.

You'll find the added performance cost will evaporate when switching to strict mode with:

```
"use strict";
```

Comment: Why does k need to be converted to a number? Is it not already a number by setting `k=20`?

Comment: typeof k is still "number". It's need to be converted to object.

Comment: There is a difference between a primitive number, and a Number object. A primitive value has no methods, and so it will be converted to an object on the fly.

Comment: Also the reason for  second to be faster is here you are doing all calculation in primitive data type by just using numbers and operators.

Comment: It looks like it's almost all due to the object conversion. I made a jsperf https://jsperf.com/number-method-vs-function and a regular function is almost identical performance to the inline comparison, but the method is 200x slower.

Comment: Just `"use strict";`, then there won't be any conversion going on and the prototype method will be as fast as the native ones